# Open plugin dialog in TinyMCE

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I have created plugin in TinyMCE to cutomize advimage plugin in it default. I added a browse button at the end of image url textbox in general tab. Here is my code:

tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAdvImgMgr',false,'src');

I can open my plugin. But I don't know how can i pass the value and get it in my plugin?
Because I want to pass ID from advimage(ID of image url image) to my plugin and then after select image from my plugin, it return image url to caller plugin(advimage)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that difficult, but depends on the point of time or action at which you want to assign the value to a variable.

You may i.e. save the value in the editor object:

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.last_selected_value = value;
```

and get it from there later on

```
ed.last_selected_value
```